# Unicode encode error for undefined character

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, encoding, twilio

I'm using Python 3 and am trying to append a string of Twillio chat messages to a list but received this error. I know encode is not working anymore in python3 and am running this through atom as people said IDLE may be causing the error.

```
text=[]
messages = client.messages.list()
for record in messages:
    print(record.body)
    text.append(record.body)
print(text)
```

Error:

> return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
>   UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character
>   '\U0001f680' in position 71: character maps to undefined

Comment: Are you sure the exception is raised when appending the string? To me, it looks like the `print()` expression might be the cause (because your console isn't configured to use UTF-8).